# dynamically set table titles with jquery's Datatables plugin - get titles from data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im searching for a way to set tables titles dynamically.
there's a search form that performs database queries, and gets a different data-set each time, according to user choice.

right now titles are hard-coded in the html.

this is how I set up the table:

```
<table id="searchResults" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>agentId</th>
      <th>confirmTime</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>amount</th>
      <th>currency</th>
      <th>amountUSD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>agentId</th>
      <th>confirmTime</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>amount</th>
      <th>currency</th>
      <th>amountUSD</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
Api.getDeposits(formData).then(function(res){
  $('#searchResults').dataTable( {
      "data": res,
      "scrollX": "100%",
      "columns": [
          { "data": "agentId" },
          { "data": "confirmTime" },
          { "data": "name" },
          { "data": "amount" },
          { "data": "currency" },
          { "data": "amountUSD" }
      ]
  });
});
```

sample data:

```
[{
  "agentId": 70,
  "amount": 250,
  "amountUSD": 250,
  "confirmTime": "2015-04-28 10:49:00",
  "currency": "USD",
  "email": "name@mail.ru",
  "name": "some name",
  "paymentMethod": "Credit Card",
  "status": "approved"
}]
```

I'd like to set tfoot, thead, according to the data I get from the server, 
so I only have one template for many situations

Comment: You do realize that your sample data not is valid JSON? It should be `"agentId": 70, "amount": 250,` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Your question does not make completely sense. If you can hardcode columns, why cant you hardcode the titles? I mean, if the `email` field is static, then the title `email` would be static too?

Anyway, I think you wants both - a template where you can pass any JSON with any number of fields and titles / field names. The following template does that :

```
<table id="example"></table>
```

script :

```
$.getJSON('url/to/json/data', function(json) {
    var keys = Object.keys(json['data'][0]),
        columns = [];
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        columns.push(
            { data: keys[i], title: keys[i] }   
        );
    }
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data : json.data,
        columns : columns
    });
});
```

This will take ***any*** JSON with *any* number of fields on the form `{ 'data' : [...] }` and make it to a dataTable with field names as titles and field objects as data.

If your JSON is on the form

```
{ "agents": [
  {
    "agentId": 70,
    ...
  }, ...
]
```

then simply rename the `data` references to `agents` ;

```
$.getJSON('url/to/json/data', function(json) {
    var keys = Object.keys(json['agents'][0]),
        columns = [];
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        columns.push(
            { data: keys[i], title: keys[i] }   
        );
    }
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data : json.agents,
        columns : columns
    });
});
```

if your JSON is a plain array `[{ ... }, { ... }]` then skip the `data` reference completely :

```
$.getJSON('url/to/json/data', function(json) {
    var keys = Object.keys(json[0]),
        columns = [];
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
        columns.push(
            { data: keys[i], title: keys[i] }   
        );
    }
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data : json,
        columns : columns
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the javascript works fine, altough when I change the HTML I get an error. are you sure about its format?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, sorry - copy paste error :( there was a not closed `<tbody>`. Have updated and minified it further. With dataTables 1.10.x and using the above approach, `<table></table>` is enough.

Comment: tnx it seems to be working, yet there's still an error of somekind. if you dont mind to take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/SMddyQ9blRgiVy2aEO2i?p=preview

Comment: @NitsanBaleli -> forked plnkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/SwDvyVDdMwJdmzhJoiZw?p=preview It was due to jQuery 2.1.4 and some internals in dataTables, you could use an older version of jQuery or use dataTables 1.10.7 or better, the "bug" was corrected some weeks ago -> https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/485b259e5c "bug" as it is jQuery who has changed.

Comment: follow up question, if you dont mind. in current syntax, Im unable to use "$('#searchResults').DataTable().fnClearTable();" before generating the table again. this is needed on every new search. any ideas? error is: "Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined"

Comment: @NitsanBaleli - Use `clear()` -> https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear() `fnClearTable()` is the "old" dataTable() API  function.

Comment: setting "destroy": true in the config-object was the way to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78909/discussion-between-nitsan-baleli-and-davidkonrad).