# Datatable title column ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I fill a datatable via ajax with the code below, but I need to rename the columns with the ajax return as well. How to do to rename the columns of the datatable with return json?

```
var table = $('#my_table').dataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    searching: false,
    bAutoWidth:false,
    bFilter: true,
    bLengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    ajax: 'clientes.php',
    dataSrc: 'data',
    columns: [ {"sTitle":"#", "data":"client_id"},{"sTitle":"Name", "data":"client_name"},{"sTitle":"Contact", "data":"client"} ]
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476323/dynamically-set-table-titles-with-jquerys-datatables-plugin-get-titles-from-d

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, thanks to @davidkonrad

```
   $.getJSON("clients.php, function(json) {
        var keys = Object.keys(json['data'][0]),
            columns = [];
        for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
            columns.push(
                { data: keys[i], title: keys[i] }
            );
        }
        var table = $('#my_table').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            bAutoWidth:false,
            bFilter: true,
            bLengthChange: false,
            responsive: true,
            data : json.data,
            columns : columns
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
        $clients_sql =
        "
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                client
        ";
    $data = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $clients_sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $id         = $row['client_id'];
        $name       = $row['client_name'];
        $phone      = $row['client_phone'];
        $data[]    = array('ID'=> $id, 'Name'=> $name, 'Phone'=> $phone);
    }

    $results['data'] = $data;
    echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: then how can i pass parameter on it such as sorting ,next button for limit etc.